# New custom theme without copying all the default files

Tags: magento

I search how to configure a custom theme in Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2 without doing a copy of all the base/default files.

The only way I can make it is to create my_theme folder in /var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/enterprise/my_theme and then in system>configuration>design to let enterprise as "Current Package Name" and my_theme as "default" in "themes".
But I'm afraid it's not the ideal way in case of upgrading Magento.

Is anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  What I typically do is create a new Package and Theme.  It will still fallback to `base/default` so you don't have to copy all of the default files into your package.  Leave `default` empty in the `Admin -> General -> Design` section.  Set the Package Name to your package and the other theme settings except for default to your theme name.  You'll only need to copy template and layout files that you plan on customizing, so there's no need to copy everything into your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried already but it didn't worked.... 
I found why in 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

"2nd Exception to Rule 6: Enterprise customers for now DO need to copy the files from enterprise/default into their custom package as a starting point. In a future release, the Enterprise files will be folded into the base/default directories but they are not in EEv1.8."